# How we can Call a FragmentActivity from a FragmentActivity in Android

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-fragmentactivity

How can we call a `FragmentActivity` from a `FragmentActivity` on click of button .Please help me in this .

And please help me to understand the difference between `FragmentActivity` and `Fragment`

Comment: Did you search in Google "difference between FragmentActivity and Fragment" ??

Comment: Why can't use the Intents similar to what we are using in Activities to Activities communication.

Comment: you can't call a activity you should start a Activity.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Similar way what we are doing with Activities

```
button1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {          
   @Override
   public void onClick(View v) {            
        startActivity(new Intent(FragmentActivity1.this, FragmentActivity2.class));
   }
});
```

Comment: one thing i want to now more how could i pass the data from one FragmentActivity to other please suggest me that also

Comment: @GauravPandey using intents.

Answer (score 1):

`FragmentActivity` is the base class for activities that want to use the support-based `Fragment` and Loader APIs.

So if you are using fragment below api level 11 you should use Fragment from the support library in which case your activity extends `FragmentActivity`

If you are using fragment in api level 11 and above you use Fragment and extend Activtiy.

Fragment is hosted by a Activity. You can't call a Activtiy. You can start another Activity from fragment or activity.